# Use the validation fields

Tags: asp.net, validation

How can i validate a field where the data in that field is a date. I want that if the field does not have this format YYYY / mm / dd  get me an error and do not go to the next screen.

This is my button.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" onclick="Button1_Click" runat="server" Text="Button" Visible="true" />
```

Comment: Did you try any asp.net validator?

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the entered date by user on button click

```
            DateTime Test;
            if(DateTime.TryParseExact(Date, "YYYY/MM/dd", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out Test) == true)
            {
                   return true;
            }
            else
            {
                     return false;
            }
```

Or you can use javascript code to validate date format using regex on client side

```
            var dateString = "2018/09/12";

            var regex = /^\d{4}\/((0\d)|(1[012]))\/(([012]\d)|3[01])$/;
            if (regex.test(dateString)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: i tried the code and it didnt work me. Can you show me an example with Javascript? I want to do the validation on Client, not on server. @Arun Kumar

Comment: I have updated my answer for javascript code. Just attach onclick event to your button and add above code.